# How does a basic VPN work?

Tags: vpn

I am trying to understand how the process of a VPN works. A lot of the text I am reading is too basic and doesn't address the technologies used in a VPN.

I'd like to know more about the security and encryption process. But I'd kind of like this in a step by step process of when those technologies come in.

example.

> User requests a page Google.com, where does the data go? to the VPN first or the ISP? What does it do when it reaches the VPN? Handshake? Key Exchange? Certificates? Then what? Google sends back its data and how does the VPN encrypt?

This doesn't have to be technical, but these are the areas the texts I'm looking at don't address.

Comment: This isn't even about Unix.

Comment: @Vlastimil The question would be too broad for that site too.  Their [Help Center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok, thank you for feedback. I don't post on Security SE often, and I didn't think much when considering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User requests a page Google.com, where does the data go?

Through many servers; [traceroute](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) will list them for you.

> To the VPN first or the ISP?

Your ISP, then your VPN.

> What does it do when it reaches the VPN?

The data is unwrapped (optionally decrypted) when it reaches the VPN from you.

> Handshake? Key Exchange? Certificates?

Optionally yes, and more (network stack get complicated)

> Then what? Google sends back its data and how does the VPN encrypt?

The encryption method depends on the VPN option you are using but one option in OpenVPN is TLS, the same technology your bank uses (some VPN connections are more secure than some bank connections; [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Security) )

---

[Wikipedia article on VPN, Virtual Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)

Comment: @Vlastimil got a link to anything official about that?